Doubt around a particular contour integral on a rectangle
I'm studying the text, "Le calcul des résidus et ses applications à la théorie des fonctions" by Ernst Lindelöf, at page 56 he starts the calculation of a contour integral on the contour $C$  defined as the rectangle symmetrical about the real axis, of height $2\delta>0$, with vertical sides passing for the points $z=\alpha$ and $z=\beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non integers such that $0<\alpha<\beta$.
He defines $\alpha\gamma'\beta$ the superior side of the rectangle and $\alpha \gamma''\beta$ the inferior side.
$\\$
The integral we have to solve is:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\pi \cot(\pi z)f(z)dz$$
where $f(z)$ is any complex function holomorphic in the interior of $C$. $\\$
He proceeds by using the fact that we can write:
$$\frac{1}{i}cot(\pi z)=-1-\frac{2}{e^{-2\pi i z}-1}$$ on the arc $\alpha\gamma'\beta$
$$\frac{1}{i}cot(\pi z)=1+\frac{2}{e^{2\pi i z}-1}$$
on the arc $\alpha\gamma''\beta$. $\\$
Note that this is simply obtained using some trigonometric formulas and is clear to me.
$\\$
With this substitutions the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\alpha\gamma''\beta}f(z)dz-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\beta\gamma'\alpha}f(z)dz+\int_{\alpha\gamma''\beta}\frac{f(z)}{e^{2\pi i z}-1}dz-\int_{\beta\gamma'\alpha}\frac{f(z)}{e^{-2\pi i z}-1}dz$$
(this passage is also clear to me).
At this point the author claims that, calling $z=\tau+it$ we have:
$$\int_{\alpha\gamma''\beta}f(z)dz=-\int_{\beta\gamma'\alpha}f(z)dz=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\tau)d\tau$$
This is the formula that doesn't seem right to me!
I thought that dividing the integrals on each of the sides of the rectangle would have made this clear, but I find that:
$$\int_{\alpha\gamma''\beta}f(z)dz=\left[-\int_{-\delta}^{0}f(\alpha+it)idt+\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\tau-i\delta)d\tau-\int_{-\delta}^{0}f(\beta+it)idt\right]$$
and
$$-\int_{\beta\gamma'\alpha}f(z)dz=-\left[\int_{0}^{\delta}f(\beta+it)idt-\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\tau+i\delta)d\tau-\int_{0}^{\delta}f(\alpha+it)idt\right]$$
I don't think that this are actually equal, so I think I have made a mistake in my calculation, can someone spot it?

What is $s$? By the residue theorem, the integral around $C$ is determined solely by the residue of $f$ at $0$. That value depends on $s$. So your question cannot be answered with knowing something about the value of $s$.

Hi, the rectangle does noth contain zero, the function f(z) is holomorphic in the interior of the contour, $s$ is a complex number, anything else is not specified in the text and I don't think is necessary, if you can only find solutions for a particular case for $s$ it will definitely be useful nonetheless

You are right - I forgot that the rectangle was to the right of the origin. If $s$ is not an integer, then one must choose a branch for $z^{-s}$ to make $f$ a function. However since the rectangle does not include the origin, such a branch can always be found that misses the contour, so $f$ can still be holomorphic in a neigbhorhood of it, which means the integral is $0$,and $\int_{C_-} = -\int_{C_+}$.  If the integrals along the two sides of the rectangle cancelled, then the formula would be correct. But like you I do not see that it would be.

However, it could be that the author meant that in the limit as $\delta \to 0$, the integrals converge to $\int_\alpha^\beta f(\tau),d\tau$. For me, the possibilities are either the author actually was saying that and you misinterpreted what they were saying, or the author, though they only meant it as a limit, absent-mindedly wrote it up as a full equality (it happens all the time). Of course you can better judge between them.

Hi, I don't think the author is talking about $\delta \rightarrow 0$ as actually in the next step $\delta$ goes to infinity, on the other hand the book talks about a more generic case, I have added some details myself to make it easier to read, but in case I understood something the wrong way I'm going to edit the question to make it more faithful to the text.
